# I have to do a Java challenge showig true/false values as 1 and 0

Tags: java, casting, boolean

I am pretty new to Java and learning from a book. I've just learned about casting types and boolean values/logical operators in the book and i was getting to a challenge. A logical operator table with true and false values program, i have to adjust it so that it shows 1 and 0 instead of true and false, so i came up with this:

```
    /* Project 2-2: a truth table for the logical operators.
   show 1 en 0 ipv true en false.
*/

class LogicalOpTableSimon {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  int p, q;
  System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

  p = 1; q = 1;

  System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
  System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
  p = 0;
  System.out.println(p + "\t" + p);


  p = 1; q = 0;

  System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
  System.out.print(q + "\t" + p + "\t");
  System.out.println(p + "\t" + q);

  p = 0; q = 1;

  System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
  System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
  System.out.println(q + "\t" + q);

  p = 0; q = 0;

  System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
  System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
  p = 1; q = 0;
  System.out.println(q + "\t" + p);
 }
}
```

This works fine and the table shows the correct values. However, i was wondering, since i've just learned in the book how to convert or cast different types, was the challenge meant to use this? In other words, can i use casting / converting to get the same result? i've tried different things, but it did not work. Or maybe i am thinking to difficult. Thanks for any tips if you have them :). By the way, the original code is:

```
    // Project 2-2: a truth table for the logical operators.
class LogicalOpTable {
public static void main(String args[]) {
boolean p, q;
System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

p = true; q = true;

System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

p = true; q = false;

System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

p = false; q = true;

System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

p = false; q = false;

System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
 }
}
```

I have searched on internet and read some more in the book. But i could not find a casting version or something like that.

Comment: You cannot cast a `boolean` to an `int` in Java. Instead, look into using `if-else` statements to show the appropriate value.

Comment: `int value = (boolean) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you need to display 0 for every false value, and 1 for every true value? Why don't you create a method `toInteger(boolean b)`, and call it for every boolean value you display?

Answer (score 1):

if you have to utilize only the stuff from the first two chapters, then the code will probably look like this

```
package ChapterTwo;
// Try this 2-2: a truth table for the logical operators. package  ChapterTwo;

public class LogicalOpTable {
public static void main(String [] args){
    boolean p, q;
    int x=0;
    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

    p = q = true;
    if(p) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if(q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p&q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p|q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p^q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (!p) x=1; System.out.println(x + "\t"); x=0;

    p = true; q = false;
    if(p) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if(q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p&q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p|q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p^q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (!p) x=1; System.out.println(x + "\t"); x=0;

    p = false; q = true;
    if(p) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if(q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p&q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p|q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p^q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (!p) x=1; System.out.println(x + "\t"); x=0;

    p = q = false;
    if(p) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if(q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p&q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p|q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (p^q) x=1; System.out.print(x + "\t"); x=0;
    if (!p) x=1; System.out.println(x + "\t"); x=0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to cast between `boolean` and `int`. `boolean` is not a numeric type in Java.

The following expressions can be used instead:

```
boolean b = true;
int i;

i = ( b ? 1 : 0 );

b = ( i != 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code....

```
public String returnedValueFromAnd(Boolean p,Boolean q)
{
    if(p&q)
     { return "true";}
    return "false";
}
 public String returnedValueFromOR(Boolean p,Boolean q)
{
    if(p|q)
     { return "true";}
    return "false";
}
 public String returnedValueFromNegation(Boolean p)
{
    if(!p)
     { return "true";}
    return "false";
}
 public String returnedValueFromXOR(Boolean p,Boolean q)
{
    if(p^q)
     { return "true";}
    return "false";
}
```

now call the methods where you want to print the value and pass the parameters p and q (as applicable).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did not had the ? yet or the making own methods part, since i am only in module 2 of 15. However, now i understand that casting is a narrowing conversion and not to convert any incompatible type. A thinking error of my own :) So, i can only guess my adjustment was legit regarding the challenge. The challenge did not say i had to use casting or if statements for that matter. There is no 'solution' for the challenge in the book, so  i never know for sure. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I too trying to learn Java from the same book came across this problem and solved it as below.

```
package ChapterTwo;

 // Try this 2-2: a truth table for the logical operators. package ChapterTwo;

public class LogicalOpTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

boolean p, q;

System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

p = true; q = true;

System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + (printBoolean2(q)) +"\t");
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = true; q = false;

System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + (printBoolean2(q)) +"\t");
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = false; q = true;

System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + (printBoolean2(q)) +"\t");
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));

p = false; q = false;

System.out.print(printBoolean(p) + "\t" + (printBoolean2(q)) +"\t");
System.out.print(printBoolean(p&q) + "\t" + printBoolean (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println(printBoolean2(p^q) + "\t" + printBoolean (!p));
}
public static String printBoolean(boolean p) {
    return p ? "1" : "0";
}
public static String printBoolean2(boolean q) {
    return q ? "1" : "0";

}
```

}